# A python parser that I'm using to Insert page information into MySQL database is yielding an empty table. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: python, mysql, parsing, xhtml

I've currently hit a roadblock with a python parser that I'm supposed to use to extract information from a website that is tracking COVID-19 cases in the state of Michigan. The parser is utilizing the XML Dom Minidom library from python and works as intended, but when I go to insert the information into a MySQL database, it yields no results, and instead has an empty table. I'm not sure what's wrong with my code, and I've tried multiple things including:

- Converting the list that stores the scraped data into a tuple
- Looping through the list and executing the insert statement
  ... and other minor tweaks to no avail. The table is supposed to have the county name, confirmed cases, and confirmed deaths in a format like this:

+--------------+----------------+-----------------+

| countyName   | confirmedCases | confirmedDeaths |

+--------------+----------------+-----------------+

Can someone please help me?

Here's the file, parser.py:

```
import sys
import xml.dom.minidom
import MySQLdb
document = xml.dom.minidom.parse(sys.argv[1])
tableElements = document.getElementsByTagName('table')

db = MySQLdb.connect(
      host="localhost",
      user="root",
      passwd="root",
      db="temp"
)

curr = db.cursor()

curr.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS cases")
curr.execute("USE cases")
query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS casesBreakdown (countyName varchar(255), confirmedCases INT, confirmedDeaths INT, newCases INT, newDeaths INT)"
curr.execute(query)

#for tr in tableElements[1].getElementsByTagName('tr'):
for tr in tableElements[0].getElementsByTagName('tr'):
      data = []
      for td in tr.getElementsByTagName('td'):
      for node in td.childNodes:
              if node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE:
                  data.append(node.nodeValue)
      x = ",".join(data)
      test = []
      for case in x.split(","):
          test.append(case)
      #print(test)
sql = "INSERT INTO casesBreakdown (countyName, confirmedCases, confirmedDeaths) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
curr.executemany(sql, test)

db.commit()
```

And here's the link to the page that I've converted into xhtml using tagsoup that I'm passing as a command line arg:
https://pastebin.com/JU8cDJJ5

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: if you un-comment ```print(test)```, what does it print?

Comment: This is the output: https://pastebin.com/1ncWhqS7

Answer (score 0):

This will work now, and I'll leave to you any final debugging.
One problem was that you were re-initialising `test = []` too often.
Also, `.executemany()` expects something like a list of tuples; just a list won't work.
Another issue could have been the indentation, but it's difficult to tell if that was in transcribing the code to SO.

```
test = []
for tr in tableElements[0].getElementsByTagName('tr'): 
    data = [] 
    for td in tr.getElementsByTagName('td'): 
        for node in td.childNodes:   
            if node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE: 
                data.append(node.nodeValue) 
            t = tuple(data) 
            if len(t) == 3: 
                test.append(t)
```

Comment: So I made the adjustments you gave on my end and the code returns this error: _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect integer value: '\xc2\xa0' for column 'confirmedDeaths' at row 4")

Comment: Ah, yes, I saw these values. I looked in the original data, and they're there too -- in other words this isn't a shortcoming of the parsing. You'll have to catch the exception and not insert those rows.